# Is this handling of ambiguities in dypgen normal or is it not?

Tags: parsing, nlp, ocaml, lexer, ambiguity

I would like to know, if this is a bug or behavior, that is intended by the inventor.

Here I have a minimal example of a dypgen grammar:

```
{
open Parse_tree
let dyp_merge = Dyp.keep_all
}

%start main
%layout [' ' '\t']

%%

main:
  | a  "\n"                                                             { $1 }

a:
  | ms b                                                                { Mt ($1,$2) }
  | b <Mt(_,_)> kon1 b                                                  { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }
  | b <Mt(_,_)> kon2 b                                                  { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }
  | b                                                                   { $1 }

b:
  | k                                                                   { $1 }
  | ns b                                                                { Nt ($1,$2) } 
  /* If you comment this line out, it will work with the permutation, but I need the 'n' ! */


   /* | b <Nt(_,_)> kon1 b                                                 { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }
   | b <Nt(_,_)> kon2 b                                                 { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }*/

k:
  | k kon1 k                                                            { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }
  | k kon2 k                                                            { Koo ($1, $2, $3) }
  | ks                                                                  { $1 }

ms:
  | words <M(_)>                                                        { $1 }
ns:
  | words <N(_)>                                                        { $1 }
ks:
  | words <K(_)>                                                        { $1 }


kon1:
  | words <U(_)>                                                        { $1 }

kon2:
  | 'y'                                                                 { Y($1) }


words:
  | chain                                                               { $1 }
throw_away:
  | word  "|" throw_away                                                { $3 }
  | word                                                                { $1 }
chain:
  | word "|" throw_away                                                 { $1 }
  | word "|" chain                                                      { $3 }
  | word                                                                { $1 }


word:
  | ('m' ['1'-'9']?)                                                    { M ($1) }
  | ('n' ['1'-'9']?)                                                    { N ($1) }

  | ('K' ['1'-'9']?)                                                    { K ($1) }

  | ('u' ['1'-'9']?)                                                    { U ($1) }
```

The example can handle such grammars:

Think about the ? and * as regular expression operators, and 's' and 'm' and 'K' as lexems.

```
  s = m? n* K
```

the 'K', 'm' and 'n' can also be replaced by these letters and a following number between 1-9
or they can be replaced by lists delimited by '|' as

```
  m1
  n1|n2
  K|K|K or K1|K2|K3
```

and these lists could also be mixed as

```
  m1|n1|K1
```

all these lists are parsed as possible ambiguities, that are globally merged – in the known sense for dypgen – with

```
  let dyp_merge = Dyp.keep_all
```

If you type in:

> ```
> m1|n1|K1  m1|n1|K1 m1|n1|K1
> ```

you get the results:

> ```
> m1  > n1  > K1
> n1  > n1  > K1
> ```

If you type in

> ```
>  K1|K2
> ```

you get

> ```
>  K1
>  K2
> ```

Now the interesting point:
In the grammar there is another feature. There is a "koordination binding" in the style of natural languages with 'u' or with 'y'.

This can bind these lists of "phrases" (a 'K' letter with optional fronting 'm' and a optinal number of 'n's) to somethin like "K1 and K2".
The grammer can parse:

```
 K1|K2 u K3|K4

 K1|K2 y K3|K4
```

And as I thought, it should have the same result.
But the difference between the "koordination bindings" is:
lexem 'u' is defined as a list of ambiguities  in the same ways as m, n, K and could also be mixed with 'K's, 'm's, 'n's
lexem 'y' is defined without this list festure.

And this makes a (surprising) difference:

> ```
>  K1|K2 u K3|K4
> ```

is parsed as:

> ```
>  koo { K1 u K4 }
>  koo { K2 u K4 }
> ```

and

> ```
>  K1|K2 y K3|K4
> ```

is parsed as:

> ```
>  koo2 { K1 y K3 }
>  koo2 { K2 y K3 }
>  koo2 { K1 y K4 }
>  koo2 { K2 y K4 }
> ```

In the first case the second part of the u-coordination is not permutated.
In the second case the second part of the coordination is permutated  (as dypgen does it with ambiguities normally).

Why this makes a difference?

(It must be somehow connected to the m's and n's, because if the rules for 'n's are left out, it works.)

Best regards and thank you for thinking about

gwf

---

The minimal example is in the style of the dypgen-demos, to try, make a folder "abc" in the demos and put all the mentioned, fully cited files in there. 
The "parse_tree":

```
type tree = 
  | M           of string
  | Mt          of tree * tree
  | N           of string
  | Nt          of tree * tree
  | K           of string
  | U           of string
  | Y           of string
  | Koo         of tree * tree * tree
  | Koo2        of tree * tree * tree * tree
```

A file "printit.ml":
    open Parse_tree

```
let print_abc abc=
  let rec aux1 t = match t with
    | Koo(x1, k, x2) -> (
        print_string "\x1b[1m\x1b[31mkoo {\x1b[21m\027[0m ";
        aux1 x1;
        print_string "";
        aux1 k;
        print_string "";
        aux1 x2;
        print_string "\x1b[1m\x1b[31m}\x1b[21m\027[0m")
    | Koo2(k1, x1, k2, x2) -> (
        print_string "\x1b[1m\x1b[31mkoo2 {\x1b[21m\027[0m ";
        aux1 k1;
        print_string " ";
        aux1 x1;
        print_string "";
        aux1 k2;
        print_string "";
        aux1 x2;
        print_string "\x1b[1m\x1b[31m}\x1b[21m\027[0m")
    | Word (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | M (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | K (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | N (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | U (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | Y (w) -> print_string (w ^ " ")
    | Nt (p, l)
    | Mt (p, l) -> (
        print_string "";
        aux1 p;
        print_string " > ";
        aux1 l;)
  in
    let aux2 t = aux1 t; print_newline () in
  List.iter aux2 abc
```

and the "main" program:
    open Parse_tree
    open Printit

```
let () = print_endline "
please try:
  K1|K2 u K3|K4
and
  K1|K2 y K3|K4
"

let lexbuf = Dyp.from_channel (Abc_parser.pp ()) stdin

let _ =
  try
    while true do
      (Dyp.flush_input lexbuf;
      try
        let pf = Abc_parser.main lexbuf in
        print_abc (List.map (fun (x,_) -> x) pf)
      with
        Dyp.Syntax_error -> Printf.printf "Syntax error\n\n"
      );
      flush stdout
    done
  with Failure _ -> exit 0
```

and the "Makefile"

```
SOURCES = printit.ml abc_parser.dyp abc.ml
REP = -I ../../dyplib
CAMLC = ocamlc $(REP)
DYPGEN = ../../dypgen/dypgen --ocamlc "-I ../../dyplib"
LIBS=dyp.cma

all: abc

SOURCES1 = $(SOURCES:.mll=.ml)
SOURCES2 = $(SOURCES1:.dyp=.ml)
OBJS = $(SOURCES2:.ml=.cmo)

abc: parse_tree.cmi $(OBJS)
    $(CAMLC) -o abc $(LIBS) $(OBJS)

.SUFFIXES: .ml .mli .cmo .cmi .dyp

.ml.cmo:
    $(CAMLC) -c $<

.mli.cmi:
    $(CAMLC) -c $<

.dyp.ml:
    $(DYPGEN) $<
    $(CAMLC) -c $*.mli

clean:
    rm -f *.cm[iox] *~ .*~ *.o
    rm -f abc
    rm -f *.extract_type *_temp.ml
    rm -f *parser.ml *parser.mli
```

Comment: I have edited an important line of my text. I confounded 'u' and 'y'  in the description of the output:
"K1|K2 y K3|K4" ->
koo { K1 y K3 }, koo { K2 y K3 }, koo { K1 y K4 }, koo { K2 y K4 }
and  "K1|K2 u K3|K4" ->  koo { K1 u K4 }, koo { K2 u K4 }

Answer (score 0):

I use dypgen but not the ambiguity handling.

A "merge point" is a point in the input stream where two parses of the *same* nonterminal are completed. If at this point the AST constructed by your action code is identical, you can safely discard either one of the two parses: there may be two ways to parse the non-terminal but the result is the same for both.

If the result is different, by default dypgen just throws one out unless you tell it to keep all the alternatives (which you have).

I'm not fully sure I understand your grammar, however there is a tricky thing in your grammar that may explain your problem.

Dypgen is GLR but it does NOT do proper GLR. If you have a recursion like

x = A x | A

y = y B | B

dypgen does tail and head optimisation and converts the recursion to a loop. You have that in your "throwaway". A real LR parser can only handle left recursion and would barf on right recursion. Dypgen handles both.

In a backtracking parser, if you have something like A*A as a grammar, it first fails on the trailing A because the leading A* ate all the A's in the input up, so it backtracks. GLR doesn't backtrack, it forks a new parse instead. But it cannot do that if it has tail or head optimised the recursion to a loop.

I suspect this is related to your problem. If you try to parse A*A* on AAAAA input, it should give 6 possible parses.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it. I wrote an email to Manu Onzon, and he said then: "As promised, I come back to you for your question about missing parse trees with your abc grammar example.
It turned out the origin of the issue was a bug in dypgen. I have now fixed it and pushed the fix to the (brand new) dypgen repo:
https://github.com/manu291/dypgen" It was the same issue and example I posted here. Then it did.

Comment: Cool! I hope he also upgraded Dypgen for Ocaml 6 (Bytes etc)