# Debugging Dypgen

Tags: parsing, debugging, ocaml, ambiguity

I'm trying to debug "dypgen", a parser-generator and so a program that is writing another program, because I noticed some bug, that is essential for my project. I have asked the developer, but he doesn't answer and I asked also over the mailing list. Nothing happend, so I try.

My project is the following, I have presented the essential part in an unanswered question on stackoverflow:
[ambiguity handling of dypgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510092/is-this-handling-of-ambiguities-in-dypgen-normal-or-is-it-not)

I found there some difference, where should be no difference in parsing two different, but very similar expressions. I have a parser, that parses

```
 K1|K2 u K3|K4
```

as:

```
 kon1 { K1 u K4 }
 kon1 { K2 u K4 }
```

and

```
 K1|K2 y K3|K4
```

as

```
 kon2 { K1 y K3 }
 kon2 { K2 y K3 }
 kon2 { K1 y K4 }
 kon2 { K2 y K4 }
```

the non-terminals "kon1" and "kon2" are implemented very similar and there should be no difference. all should be a permutation as the second case.

I run the ocamldebugger with a script through the two cases and wrote the output into two files (2-4 MB). Here is screenshot of meld (an editor, that can find differences between files and show them graphically), that shows a little part of the comparison. On the border you can see two major parts in green, where differences show up.

One thing with this comparison is, that I would like to get rid of all these steps through List, Set, Hashtable modules and see just the important parts, that go out from my files. I would like to have a function in ocamldebug as "step over" not step into.

But there is another problem, precisely, that this automaton, that dypgen creates, consists of lists of objects and functions. List.fold is used to work on these lists. How I can find out, where I am in the parser-automaton with these List.fold-calls?

thx for any help!

[image: difference between debuggung case (A) and case (B)]